# Rails-Dynamically display data based on collection select

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a bunch of data in a single model that I want to display based on collection select (drop down) box. The section data looks like this...

```
class CreateSections < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :sections do |t|
      t.string :supervisor
      t.string :catagory
      t.string :title
      t.string :description
      t.string :days
      t.string :start_date
      t.string :end_date
      t.string :start_time
      t.string :end_time
      t.string :course_id
      t.string :room
      t.string :building
      t.string :location
      t.string :tuition
      t.string :lab_fee
      t.string :insurance_fee
      t.string :technology_fee

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

My collection select looks like this...

```
  collection_select(:section, :section_id, @sections, :id, :title)
```

So the user will select the title from the drop down, and I would like to display the description. Ideally I would like to do this with jquery.

EDIT

Here is more info on what the html looks like...

```
 <select id="section_section_id" name="section[section_id]"><option value="1">Long Title</option>
<option value="2"> Alternative Investments for Small Business  NEW</option>
<option value="3">Bookkeeping Basics for the Natural Products Industry  NEW  </option>
...
```

In app/assets/javascripts/sections.js I now have...

```
$(function(){
  $("#section_section_id").change(function(){
    alert('wintas');
  })
})
```

So now based on the option that is selected, I would like to display the value associated with that option.

Comment: what related data you want to show when an option is selected ?

Comment: So you can see in the collection select I am displaying title. There is a description field in the same model/table. When the user selects a title I would like to display the associated description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `options_for_select` to place the info you want to display in data attribute of that options

Assuming you have the select in context of a form

```
<%= f.select :section, :section_id, options_for_select(@sections.map{ |s| [s.title, s.id, {'data-description'=>s.description}] }) %>
```

This will generate the html like this

```
<option value="2" data-description= "description of 2"> Alternative Investments for Small Business  NEW</option>
<option value="3" data-description="description of 3">Bookkeeping Basics for the Natural Products Industry  NEW  </option>
```

You can then use js to show it

Here is a working demo of js

http://jsfiddle.net/Tt3TS/

Hope that helps